# Compiling error when updated to last version of LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, luatex

This error appear when trying to build the document:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.20 \IFTEX@let
           {vtexdvi}{false}
```

How can I work around this problem ?

Comment: What's your distribution?

Comment: example document?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Update hyperref using your miktex or texlive system

Comment: I get the same error here. A tracker was opened [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/137) then closed, but the problem does not seem to be solved. All my packages are up to date though. The problem might come from the fact that the folder containing the sources has changed